# Bootstrap variable passed over to Flask

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap, flask, flask-wtforms

First of all sorry if that's a silly question, but I am kind of stuck..

I want to pass a couple of variables from my HTML/Bootstrap page to Flask. The variables are obtained in a form.

The variable is to be selected from a dropdown. Once the variable is selected from mySQL2 it should be stored in `customername`.

At the moment I've got this sample code which does not work at all.

```html
<form action="" class="form-group" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="selectcustomer">Select your customer</label>
        <input
            <select class="form-control" id="selectcustomer">
                {% for j in mySQL2 %}
                <option>{{j[2]}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select> value="{{request.form.customername}}">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="customername" value="{{request.form.customername}}">
    </div>
    <br>
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How can I post the selected value into `customername`?

The form looks like this: 
[image: Screenshot from Broswer]

I need the selection field to be a dropdown. Once a value is selected it should be stored in `customername`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what doesn't work?  Generally, HTML form values (input, select/option) will be POSTed back to the server at the URL specified in the form's action attribute.  Your action is blank -- is that intentional?

Comment: Sorry, just added the post with a screenshot. No its not on purpose. I need the selected value to be posted and sent to the server.

Comment: I'm no pro but is this `<input  <select> ... </select> value="{{request.form.customername}}">` valid? It looks a bit off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before form submission can't get the submit values. To get posted data in view use:

```
request.form["selectcustomer"]
```

*note:* html `select` tag should have a name attribute `<select name="selectcustomer" ...>` so you can get value with name not the select id.

Lets say you have a view as follows:

```
def customer():
    customername = ""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        customername = request.form["customername"]
    return render_template("yourhtmlfile", customername=customername)

#yourhtml
...
{{customername}}
```

Comment: Thanks, in the end I went for wtforms, which I find somewhat ugly, or havent figured out a way in html to make them look OK. Looking at your suggestion I guess I should have taken off the input, the variable is then stored via </select> value="{{request.form.customername}}"> and can be called in flask..